# Added C src files to my C++ project, but they cannot find "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, precompile

I have a simple VS C++ project that consists of a few headers and one source file that houses main(). I am using VS's default method of using precompiled headers with stdafx.h. So my one main.cpp has:

> #include "stdafx.h"

at the top. For this configuration, everything compiles and runs fine.
However, I needed to add some C src and header files to my project that has data and function calls that I need to use. So I added these (3 .c files and 1 .h file) using the usual method: Add > Existing Item > choose file. But when I tried to compile I get

> Error C101: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

So I went back to my new .c src files and added #include "stdafx.h" to the top, but VS is throwing

> E1696 Error: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Does VS's precompiler work with C files in a C++ project or do I need to reconfigure it somehow?

EDIT: The reason I chose to go with the default method of using precompiled headers is because although *my* code isn't very large, I am using large header libraries like Boost and Eigen.

Comment: Is stdafx.h in the same folder as the .c file?

Comment: You probably don't need `"stdafx.h"`. It is a non-standard header. I never used it -I don't have it on my Linux system- and all the free software I looked into don't use or need that `sddafx.h`.

Comment: You could just disable precompiled headers. It does not really help for small projects anyways.

Comment: Do not add unrelated C files into C++ project. Compile them separately either as static or dynamic library and link that library.

Comment: I suggest you choose an empty project.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch "stdafx.h" is just a placeholder name for precompiled headers used by visual studio vanilla project templates.

Comment: I heard that rumor (but I have the privilege to never have used Windows) but people don't need it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Only those people who don't care about compilation times don't need it. Actually precompiled headers are [supported by gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html). So Linux people can utilize them as well.

Comment: I sometimes do you PCH, but in practice (on a program worked upon by a few persons) it does not matter much. And other colleagues also observed that. Precompiled headers could matter for large software code base.

Comment: No Windows! Please tell me they at least let you have a door so you can go outside! @ VTT if you put nothing in it, and few people throwing together a homework assignment do, "stdafx.h" don't do squat. It's just cargo cult at that point.

Comment: Anyway, @VTT you almost certainly have the right answer in your first comment. Recommend Expanding on the why and making a formal answer out of it.

Comment: In my experience, `stdafx.h` has caused more problems than its worth, including apps running on windows.  I always uncheck *precompiled headers*.  The problem with precompiled headers is that if you change one of the headers, it has to be compiled again, no savings of build time there.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I appreciate my lightning fast compile time, but Jesus H. Christ there *has* to be a better way of implementing PCH than VS's method. I constantly little noisy errors from it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The whole point of precompiled headers is to include there stuff that is *commonly used* but *rarely changes*. That is standard library, boost, gsl or whatever *third-party* libraries are utilized in your project. Definitely not some headers that you are going to modify yourself every 5 minutes.